# Python, Webbrowser and Gmail

Tags: python, browser, gmail

Hey friends. I want to open Gmail but with a particular account. My python script has a list of gmail accounts and i want the one to open in gmail which has been clicked/selected. I tried using the credentials in the URL but am not happy with that as I don't want to put the users password in the URL + it doesn't work :).

I'm using webbrowser.open(URL) to open gmail.

Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have *no clue* if this would work, but it may be worth a shot.

You could try to spoof the browser and login via urllib and grab the [cookie](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/cookielib.shtml). Then you could programatically put the cookie in the browsers cookie directory and launch the browser to gmail.

It seems like it would work if you can get the browser+google to believe the cookie is a valid one, but it may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you're not using IMAP to interact with the Gmail account?

```
import imaplib
M=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
M.login('myemailaddress@gmail.com','password')

# do things!

M.close()
M.logout()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Where is the script running? What is it triggered by? It it just supposed to open up Gmail in a browser and login so that a user can use it? Or are you trying to automatically interact with the Gmail account. If the latter is true then you want to use IMAP/SMTP.